# NestJs, how to pass data to a custom decorator, the data I want to pass are parameters of the url?

Tags: nestjs

My controller

```
@Get(':param/')
 async simples(
   @CustomDecorator(param)
 ) {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Get(':id')
  async simples( @CustomDecorator(@Param('id') id: number) ) { }
```

Comment: Does this still work?
I'm trying to pass a `@param` into a PipeTransform on a `@Query`,  I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: `@Query(new GroupValidationPipe(@Param('reportType') report: string) ) downloadParams: DownloadPlanningDto`